# Does every smooth manifold admit a smooth $\Delta$-complex structure?

Tags: manifolds

I know that every smooth manifold $M$ admits a **triangulation**. That means, there exists some simplicial complex $K$ homeomorphic to $M$.

Does this mean that it also admits a smooth **$\Delta$-complex structure**? In Hatcher, this is defined as

> a collection of smooth maps $\sigma_\alpha :\Delta_\alpha^n\to M$
>   satisfying
>
> 1. The restriction of each map to each face is injective, and each point of X is in the image of exactly one such restriction.
> 2. Each restriction to a face is one of the maps $\sigma_\beta : \Delta^{n−1}\to M$.
> 3. A set $U\subset M$ is open iff $\sigma^{-1}(A)$ is open in $\Delta^n$ for each $\sigma$.

Comment: A triangulation is a special case of a $\Delta$-complex.

Comment: Yeah, but the formulations are different. Let me clarify my question.

Comment: First, note that the standard result is that a smooth manifold admits a smooth triangulation, not just a triangulation. That is to say, in the homeomorphism you write down, it's smooth on each simplex. But then my first comment applies again: the collection of maps from simplices you get from a triangulation gives you a $\Delta$-complex structure. The latter is a special case.